# Cannot store in Firebase database and storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner in android studio. I am trying to save image,title,post written by user in the firebase database and storage.

Since I have not made sign-up page,I have set the rules in realtime database as == true for both read and write .also request.auth==true in storage rules.

But it is not getting saved in the database. Progress dialogue is never dismissed.
when I coded a toast to check, I got to know that the problem lies in onSuccess method.

Log shows some auth error.

Please tell me what correction should I make in my code?

```
package com.awani.simpleblogapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton setImage;
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

private Button submitButton;
private EditText titleField;
private EditText postField;
private Uri imageUri = null;

private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private ProgressDialog progressbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    setImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.setImage);
    submitButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    titleField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleField);
    postField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.postField);
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(); //this directs us to the root director of the storage
    mDatabase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("blog");

    progressbar = new ProgressDialog(this);

    setImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

        }
    });

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startPosting();

        }
    });

}





private void startPosting() {

    progressbar.setMessage("Posting to the blog.... ");
    progressbar.show();

    final String title_val = titleField.getText().toString();
    final String post_val=postField.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(post_val) && imageUri!=null){

        StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Blog_Images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUri =  taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();//provides us download Uri

                DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();

                newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                newPost.child("Post").setValue(post_val);
                newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUri.toString());

                progressbar.dismiss();;

                //make new intent to direct the uer after submiting
               // startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        imageUri = data.getData();

        setImage.setImageURI(imageUri);

    }


}

}
```

Comment: add read and write rule as true

Comment: +ashish,I did it.still not working.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate your user(s) straight away or just trying to get the saving to storage to work first?

Comment: +kobi-wan-kenobi I am trying to get the saving to storage work first as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: As stated by @ashish, ensure your Firebase Storage access rules are something like: `allow read, write;` . Don't make my mistake and assume your Realtime Database rules apply to your Firebase Storage as well.

Answer (score 0):

i have worked on something like that.. please use this code, feel free to edit it to your taste, but so far the code is working

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

 import java.net.URI;

public class PostActivity4Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton mSelectImage;
private EditText mPostTitle;
private EditText mPostDesc;
private Button mSubmitBtn;
private Uri mImageUri = null;

private static final int  GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

private StorageReference mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_activity4_home);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Home");

    mSelectImage = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
    mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
    mPostDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descField);

    mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submitbtn);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });


    mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPosting();
        }
    });

}

private void startPosting() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Posting...");
    mProgress.show();

     final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
     final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null){

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("HomePostImages").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                mProgress.dismiss();

                DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                newPost.child("Title").setValue(title_val);
                newPost.child("Desc").setValue(desc_val);
                newPost.child("Image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity4Home.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected  void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK);
     mImageUri = data.getData();

    mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
}
```

}